# How can I change bottom line colour based on EditText state?

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` which I set its state to **editable=false** on first load like this:

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_personalPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/editbox_profile_style"
        android:textColorHint="#4d4d4d"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:editable="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/user_telephone" />
```

When I touch a button just at its right, its state changes to **editable=true**. 
I want to hide the bottom line of the `EditText` to *transparent* when **editable=false**, and I want to show the regular line when **editable=true**.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with appcompat v7

overriding the value for `colorControlActivated`, `colorControlHighlight` and `colorControlNormal`

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#e6e6e6</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#e6e6e6</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: PS: I will accept when allowed... So short time to answer for you!